# MSCRM 2011 SiteMinder ADFS

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs2.0, siteminder

I am new to MSCRM trying to adopt its security model and integrate with our existing applications. Need a clear understanding with respect to integration between MSCRM system and our existing applications.

Our current application is uses SiteMinder for authentication, business need is to integrate MSCRM from this application without login challenge again. After going through the claim based authenticaiton, ADFS 2.0, ADFS with SiteMinder documentation, some basic questions,

--> can MSCRM work if federated with ADFS SiteMinder ?

--> If so, how the user setup will work in MSCRM ?

Can any body done these MSCRM - ADFS - SiteMinder integration ? i could find the disjoint documentation ADFS - Siteminder, MSCRM - ADFS, but not so sure if relying application (MSCRM) will work with SiteMinder tokens.

Any suggestions appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

The big question would be if what SAML Defaults your Siteminder is providing.

Setup would be simliar to ADFS 2.0 install the certificate from siteminder on the CRM Server to make him beable to proof the token and tell CRM where it can download the federationmetadata file from siteminder.